# Jquery UI tag-it widget - what's the best way to disable entries?

Tags: jquery-ui, tag-it

For the Jquery UI tag-it widget, I'd like to disable text input into the class="ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete-input" textbox which contains all the tags.

My purpose is to just allow certain people the ability to delete inappropriate tags, but not allow anybody to add tags (which are auto-generated).

Is the best thing for me to edit the tag-it .js file and add a disable="disable" for that field? If I do that, won't that prevent the contents of that field from being submitted? Or does that matter as long as the associated hidden field is submitted?

Or is there a better way of doing this (an overriding style?) without modifying the tag-it file itself?

Thanks,

doug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In tag-it.js I replaced this line:

```
this._tagInput = $('<input type="text"').addClass('ui-widget-content');
```

with this:

```
this._tagInput = $('<input type="text" readonly="readonly"/>').addClass('ui-widget-content');
```

adding the readonly="readonly" attribute. That had the desired effect of preventing input but still allowing users to delete inappropriate auto-generated tags.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question as original op.
But as the question is 2 and a half years old, and tag-it version is changed.
The accepted answer needs to be updated to the folowing in

> tag-it.js around line 478:

from:

```
        if (this.options.readOnly){
            tag.addClass('tagit-choice-read-only');
        }
```

To:

```
            if (this.options.readOnly){
            tag.addClass('tagit-choice-editable');
            // Button for removing the tag.
            var removeTagIcon = $('<span></span>')
                .addClass('ui-icon ui-icon-close');
            var removeTag = $('<a><span class="text-icon">\xd7</span></a>') // \xd7 is an X
                .addClass('tagit-close')
                .append(removeTagIcon)
                .click(function(e) {
                    // Removes a tag when the little 'x' is clicked.
                    that.removeTag(tag);
                });
            tag.append(removeTag);            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is under the documentation of git repository having the [documentation](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it), under the Properties section:

> $("#myTags").data("ui-tagit").tagInput.addClass("fancy"); //Obviously
>   if you want to do something with class...

This translates to the solution for this below, in my personal implementation style, and probably the only way I could get this to work:

```
 $("#myTags").data("ui-tagit").tagInput.prop('disabled' , true);
```

This is if I understand your question correctly.
Note: ReadOnly does not make the tags un-editable.

As far as going through the tags, you could use ..

```
var x = $("#myTags").tagit("assignedTags");
```

Make it as an input field, and that ensures its "singleFieldNode" meaning tags are `,` (comma) separated. That way you can parse through it (split for commas(`,`) into an object, or however you want to do it)

PS: To apply any of the snippets above, simply change to the "id" of the HTML element that contains TagIt, and your code would work correctly.
JQuery TagIt v2.0

Comment: Thanks for the help (Tomasz, Moritz), converting to correctly apply snippets. New to answering on the platform, and still haven't read the documentation on how things work to answer nicely. My latest edit was to apply generic/consistent "id" on the answer.